# Avoiding code duplication in if else print block

Tags: c++, macros, duplicates

I hate the code duplication here. How to make it more concise? Is another macro for the repeated text a good idea?
I am having a strange feeling that I am missing something glaringly obvious as well.

```
      #define CHECK(para_1, para_2, para_3, epic_fail) { \
      if (para_2 != para_3) { \
        size_t __bytes; \
        if(#para_1 == "special") { \
          __bytes = snprintf( \
            NULL, 0, \
            #para_1 \
              " this_thing '%s'(%p) doesn't go well with special this_thing '%s'(%p)", \
            para_2, para_2, para_3, para_3); \
        } else { \
          __bytes = snprintf( \
            NULL, 0, \
            #para_1 " this_thing '%s'(%p) doesn't go well with unique_goldfish this_thing '%s'(%p)", \
            para_2, para_2, para_3, para_3); \
        } \
        char * message = \
          reinterpret_cast<char *>(rmw_allocate(__bytes + 1)); \
        if(#para_1 == "special") { \
          snprintf( \
            message, __bytes + 1, \
            #para_1 \
              " this_thing '%s'(%p) doesn't go well with special this_thing '%s'(%p)", \
            para_2, para_2, para_3, para_3); \
        } else{ \
          snprintf( \
            message, __bytes + 1, \
            #para_1 " this_thing '%s'(%p) doesn't go well with unique_goldfish this_thing '%s'(%p)", \
            para_2, para_2, para_3, para_3); \
        } \
        SET_THE_ERROR(message); \
        free_the_mem(message); \
        epic_fail; \
      } \
    }
```

Comment: `__bytes` is a reserved identifier

Comment: The `if(#para_1 == "special")` test is probably undefined behavior, and is likely to always fail. You probably want some `enum`

Comment: Why is this a macro?  it should be a function (maybe inline, but I don't really see why) or at worst a much simpler macro that calls a helper function to do the real work (similar to how `assert()` is usually implemented).

Comment: If you really use C++ maybe you should think abou lambdas. Since you can save them as a variable and use multiple times. ( `auto function = [](){//Some code};` )

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here's the [original snippet](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/master/rmw/include/rmw/impl/cpp/macros.hpp/#L68) for some context, and here's my [commit to address an issue which caused duplication](https://github.com/madratman/rmw/commit/115a46851a2748f7d4489d9bd1c084ec3a782eb7)
Please ignore the commit message for now, it was a quick squash, didn't bother

Comment: Agree about lambdas, I do use them. But this macro is being used elsewhere in the organization's repos. For why it's a macro, I think it could be a function, but I don't want to change that, that would cause changes in many other repos of the project.

Comment: About the undefined behavior, one of the team members [told me the same thing!](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/pull/55). But [gist_1](https://gist.github.com/madratman/122193f12f7863633c59) and [gist_2](https://gist.github.com/madratman/ad83822c6fc40078b6eb) don't cause errors (only compiler warnings). 
Am I still wrong here, or is it good?

Comment: Comparing two C-style string pointers won't result in undefined behavior, but it is either unspecified behavior (when two string literals are involved) or just not going to do what you want (if you want two different string pointers that each point to the same string value to compare as equal).

Answer (score 1):

Use macro in macro:

```
#define CHECK_PRINT(n) snprintf( \
    message, __bytes + n, \
    #para_1 " this_thing '%s'(%p) doesn't go well with unique_goldfish this_thing '%s'(%p)", \
    para_2, para_2, para_3, para_3); 

#define CHECK(para_1, para_2, para_3, epic_fail) { \
    if (para_2 != para_3) { \
        size_t __bytes; \
        if(#para_1 == "special") { \
          __bytes = CHECK_PRINT(n); \
        } else { \
          __bytes = CHECK_PRINT(n); \
        } \
       ...
```

Comment: Missed something glaringly obvious indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more function for checking para conditions.
Hope this explain your question

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for a major refactoring, you might want to consider something like:

```
static
void check_impl( char const* p1, char const* p2, char const* p3)
{
    char const* special_or_unique = (strcmp(p1,"special") == 0) ? "special" : "unique_goldfish";
    char const* fmt = "%s this_thing '%s'(%p) doesn't go well with %s this_thing '%s'(%p)";
    char* message = NULL;

    size_t bytes = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt,
                            p1, 
                            p2, (void*) p2, 
                            special_or_unique, 
                            p3, (void*) p3);

    message = (char*) malloc(bytes+1);
    if (message) {
        snprintf(message, bytes+ 1, fmt,
                    p1, 
                    p2, (void*) p2, 
                    special_or_unique, 
                    p3, (void*) p3);

        SET_THE_ERROR(message);
        free(message);
    }
    else {
        // some error handler?
    }
}



#define CHECK(para_1, para_2, para_3, epic_fail) \
    do { \
        /*should this really be: if (strcmp((para_2), (para_3)) != 0) { */ \
        if ((para_2) != (para_3)) {  \
            check_impl( #para_1, (para_2), (para_3)); \
            epic_fail;  \
        }   \
    } while (0)
```